# Unity How to get current pressed UI button in Android

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, unity-ui

How do i get current pressed UI button on Android.
I am using
GameObject thisbutton = UnityEngine.EventSystems.EventSystem.current.currentSelectedGameObject;

But i am getting null reference on Andoird logcat. Works fine on editor

Answer (score 0):

Call this function when the button is pressed

```
public void ButtonClicked()
   {
       string name = EventSystem.current.currentSelectedGameObject.name;
   }
```

Comment: I am already doing this but. It doesnt return the proper pressed button for some reason. For instance if i press button 3, it returns button 5 or button 6